# How to initialize std::vector of function pointers to operator overloads?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to make a `std::vector` out of pointers to four operator overloading member functions. What's wrong with this:

```
struct Fractal
{   int dividee;
    int divisor;

    Fractal operator +(Fractal other)
    {   [not important]
    }

    Fractal operator -(Fractal other)
    {   [not important]
    }

    Fractal operator *(Fractal other)
    {   [not important]
    }

    Fractal operator /(Fractal other)
    {   [not important]
    }
};

int main()
{   Fractal fractal = Fractal{3, 10};

    typedef Fractal(*fractalOperator)(Fractal, Fractal);
    std::vector<fractalOperator> ops =
    {   &Fractal::operator +,
        &Fractal::operator -,
        &Fractal::operator *,
        &Fractal::operator /
    };
}
```

Compiler says

```
error: could not convert '{&Fractal::operator+, &Fractal::operator-, &Fractal::operator*, &Fractal::operator/}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<Fractal (*)(Fractal, Fractal)>'
 };
```

Which is not very helpful. What's the correct way? I'm using c++14.

Comment: If you'd reduced your example by getting rid of the `vector`, and instead trying something simpler - `fractalOperator op = &Fractal::operator +;` for instance, you'd have gotten an error message that said the conversion was not possible and listed the mismatching types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `typedef` is for a pointer to function which takes two `Fractal`s and returns a `Fractal`. What you want is a [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions), which has a different syntax.

```
typedef Fractal(Fractal::*fractalOperator)(Fractal);
```

Or, with a `using` alias, which I find easier to read

```
using fractalOperator = Fractal(Fractal::*)(Fractal);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is:

```
std::vector<std::function<Fractal(Fractal, Fractal)>> ops = {
    [](Fractal l, Fractal r){ return l + r; },
    [](Fractal l, Fractal r){ return l - r; },
    [](Fractal l, Fractal r){ return l * r; },
    [](Fractal l, Fractal r){ return l / r; },
};
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't matter whether the operators are implemented as member functions or free functions.

Under the covers, the lambda are stored in `function` objects with the correct calling signature, and those are stored in the `vector`.

Comment: Accepting the other answer since it's more precisely what I asked, but this is useful tip too, so upvoting.